# Connecting a WCF service to an external API

Tags: c#, wcf, api, wsdl, wadl

I need to connect a **WCF** service to an external **WCF** service via an **API** which is returning data in the **JSON** format.

I have been looking at **wsdl** and **wadl** to achieve this but I am not sure whether they were implemented on the external service or how to go about accessing them.

`<serviceMetadata>` has been enabled on the external service.

From what I have seen so far **wsdl** seems to be outdated and only compatible with **SOAP**, does that sound right? So this being correct, I would naturally prefer to use **wadl**.

Are these my only options and if so are there any good guides that walk through how to implement these?

Thanks.

Comment: WSDL is **not** outdated, but yes, it is for SOAP.  If you're receiving JSON, you're most likely hitting a REST service.

Comment: @Tim Hi Tim, yes it is a restful service. Oh ok I just assumed, as it was mentioned in a lot of legacy Microsoft documentation.

Comment: You could use something like `HttpClient` to connect from your service to the external REST service.  Do a Google search for writing .NET client for REST services or something like that and there should be plenty of examples.  No WSDL or proxy involved :)  I have a WCF service at work that connects to a third party RESTful service (but it returns XML, not JSON) that uses `HttpClient` to send the request and consume the response - it's nothing but a few lines of code.  Very simple.

Comment: @Tim Awesome thank you, that was heaps easier than I thought it was going to be. If you post as answer I will mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is based on a stripped down version of something I implemented at work and modified (but not tested) to work with JSON (based on some other answers here and on the web):

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("http://somedomain.com/serviceAddress").Result;

string responseContent = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```

There are numerous ways to do this, but the above code demonstrates how easy it is (or should be, at least) to do this.

Note that I used the `Result` property for the async calls; if you're making this call from within a method marked as `async`, you could also do:

```
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("http://somedomain.com/serviceAddress");

string responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

`HttpClient` is in the `System.Net.Http` namespace.

Comment: Ok awesome I have something pretty similiar to this though I can't get it to work. I tried your versions and have the same issue. What using directives have you used, because I have the following errors HttpClient does not contain a definition for 'GetAsync' + 'GetStringAsync' + 'DefaultRequestHeaders'?

Comment: @Corey - What version of .NET are you using?  It looks like `System.Net.Http` is 4.5; you may need to use `System.Net.WebClient` or `System.Net.WebRequest`.  Otherwise make sure you add a reference to `System.Net.Http` to your project and the using directive `using System.Net.Http;` to your code.

Comment: I am using .net Framework 4.5. Yeah I have already added those references in and still the same errors.

Comment: Yeah I tried that and it didn't work, its like the client variable doesn't contain those methods.

Comment: Okay got it. It was a conflict between a public class that I had created. Thanks for your help.