# 400 Bad Request response when consuming WCF endpoint

Tags: c#, wcf, .net-core

I'm getting a 400 Bad Request response when trying to make a request to an endpoint of a locally iis hosted WCF service using HttpClient. The call is implemented within a .NET Core microservice and is as follows:

```
    private static readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    
    public async Task<ActionResponse> SomeAction(ActionRequest request, ShoppingCart shoppingCart) {

        //non-related code
 
        var requestObject = new WcfServiceRequest() {
            OrderData = shoppingCart.Order,
            VoucherCode = request.VoucherCode,
            Check = request.Check,
            Identifier = shoppingCart.Order.Identifier,
            DontGenerateNewOrdernumber = true
        };
    
        var requestContent = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(requestObject, settings);
        HttpResponseMessage serviceResponse = await client.PostAsync(new Uri("http://localhost/SomeApplicationServicePortal/Services/WcfPortalService.svc/web/SomeEndpoint"), 
        new StringContent(requestContent, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));

       //more non-related code

    }
```

On the other hand, the contract is as follows:

```
[DataContract]
public class WcfServiceRequest {
    [DataMember]
    public string Identifier { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public Order OrderData { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public Client ClientData { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string VoucherCode { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public bool Check;
    [DataMember]
    public bool ExistingOrder;
    [DataMember]
    public bool DontGenerateNewOrdernumber { get; set; }
}
```

At this moment I have no idea about what to do. I would be very thankful if anyone helps me to fix this.

**EDIT:**

The WCF serviceModel contained in its web.config file is as follows:

```
 <system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="BasicBinding" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
      <security>
        <transport>
          <extendedProtectionPolicy policyEnforcement="Never" />
        </transport>
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="webHttpEndpointBinding" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
    </binding>
    <binding name="webHttpEndpointBindingSsl" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
      <security mode="Transport" />
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
    </binding>
  </webHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="ApplicationManager.ServicePortal.Services.WcfPortalServiceBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="WebBehavior">
      <webHttp />
      <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="ApplicationManager.ServicePortal.Services.WcfPortalServiceBehavior" name="ApplicationManager.ServicePortal.Services.WcfPortalService">
    <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicBinding" contract="ApplicationManager.ServiceContracts.IApplicationManagerServicePortal">
      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost" />
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="web" behaviorConfiguration="WebBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="webHttpEndpointBinding" contract="ApplicationManager.ServiceContracts.IApplicationManagerServicePortal" />
    <endpoint address="web" behaviorConfiguration="WebBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="webHttpEndpointBindingSsl" contract="ApplicationManager.ServiceContracts.IApplicationManagerServicePortal" />
  </service>
</services>
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" /></system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: You can take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20879297/connecting-a-wcf-service-to-an-external-api

Comment: Tried exactly the same but using PostAsync rather than GetAsync (as I need to add the payload to the request), still getting 400 Bad Request response: {StatusCode: 400, ReasonPhrase: 'Bad Request', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionResponseContent, Headers:{  Cache-Control: private  Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0  X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319  X-Powered-By: ASP.NET  Date: Wed, 09 Jun 2021 07:40:43 GMT  Content-Type: text/html  Content-Length: 3869}}

Comment: I forgot to include some comments at the start/end of "SomeAction" method to let everyone know that the method is actually bigger, but that's just the piece of code related to the HTTP request.

Comment: After adding some traces, I noticed the following exception, so I thought it was a good idea to edit the description and include the WCF serviceModel -> System.InvalidOperationException: The Address property on ChannelFactory.Endpoint was null.  The ChannelFactory's Endpoint must have a valid Address specified.